# Parsing an array

Tags: c#

I am in need of parsing an array or characters that is a fixed length but can have just about any combination of letter or number.  My 50 digit array looks like this:  NL1NAMEOFCO-B032144221111000100600000-A35499001

This array represents a vast combination of settings within our product.  I need to extract all reference designators in the array.  The first 3 characters represent a particular model NL1, the next 8 characters represent a company NAMEOFCO.  The ‘-‘ will always be in the same location.  The B (digit 13) represents some value, etc, etc.  Also, some values are represented by 2 digits.  Digits 20 & 21 (which store the value 22), represent some specific settings.

So by now you get the idea.  I can parse the array and extract the values I need by using the following code:

```
String Company = ConfigCode[3].ToString() +
                 ConfigCode[4].ToString() + 
                 ConfigCode[5].ToString() + 
                 ConfigCode[6].ToString() + 
                 ConfigCode[7].ToString() + 
                 ConfigCode[8].ToString() +
                 ConfigCode[9].ToString() +
                 ConfigCode[10].ToString();
```

This works without any problems, but to me, there should be an easier way of doing this.  I would have thought the following would work, but it does not.

```
String Company = ConfigCode[3..10].ToString();
```

Can someone explain to me why it doesn’t work and what would be a better way of extracting the information I need?

Thanks!

Comment: string.Substring(startIndex, length) is a bit nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `String.Substring` method is what you're looking for.  The signature for the overloaded method you're looking for is:

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex,
    int length
```

)

The documentation for it is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

For example, your Company name would be (going by the description of a character length of `8`):

`string CompanyName = configCode.Substring(3, 8);`

Comment: Not length of 8?  The code shows 6, but the question mentions 8 chars.

Comment: @ryanyuyu good catch, I was going by the code :]  I'll update

Comment: Thanks!  Substring is exactly what I was looking for.  Also corrected mistake in question.  Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned before, you can use the Substring extension method like so:

```
String Company = ConfigCode.Substring(3, 8);
```

The [square-bracket operators for strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx), like in `ConfigCode[3]`, actually return individual chars at that specific index.  And C# isn't as pretty as other programming languages where stuff like `array[3..10]` actually gives you a portion of an array (or in this case, a string).

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the info!